# How to dock a View component to the top of the screen while scrolling in react native?

Tags: react-native

The application i'm making has a scrollview which contains a child and i want to dock the child to the top when it reaches top of the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show any object at the top of the screen by using `absolute` position.

```
exampleStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0
}
```

In order to create a docking effect, you can render the child with the above styling after some scrolling. You can check the scroll value by setting `onScroll` of ScrollView component. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

Answer (score 0):

use stickyHeaderIndices={[0,2,3] where the array represent the immediate child of the ScrollViewuse stickyHeaderIndices={[0,2,3]} props of the ScrollView where the array represent the immediate child of the ScrollView that needs to be docked